# Proof: $z$ is a limit point of $(z_n)_{n\geq 1} \quad \iff \quad z$ is a limit point of $(z_n+w_n)_{n\geq 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $(z_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence and $(w_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{C}$ a null sequence (sequence tending to zero).

**Proof that:** $z$ is a limit point of $(z_n)_{n\geq 1} \iff z$ is a limit point of $(z_n+w_n)_{n\geq 1}$

**My attempt:**

For "$\Rightarrow$":

Let $z$ be the limit point of $(z_n)_{n\geq 1}$. We know that $(w_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a null sequence, thus $w_n\overset{n\to \infty}\longrightarrow 0$. $0$ is a neutral element regarding addition, hence $z$ is a limit point of $(z_n+w_n)_{n\geq 1}$

Comment: For "$\Leftarrow$" you can apply the same argument to $z_n = (z_n + w_n) - w_n$.

Comment: Proof looks fine, but some might complain about a lack of rigor and explicit writing, but that's only a problem for certain contexts. The reverse should be clear to you as well. Hint, what does $\{z_n+w_n\}$ converge to?

Comment: Thank you Martin, that's a clever move!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely have the right idea, but you might want to elaborate that if $z$ is a limit point of $(z_n)_n$ then $z_{n_k} \to z$ for some subsequence $(z_{n_k})_k$ of $(z_n)_n$. It follows that $(z_{n_k} + w_{n_k})_k$ is a subsequence of $(z_n + w_n)_n$ with
$$
 z_{n_k} + w_{n_k} \to z + 0 = z
$$
so that $z$ is a limit point of $(z_n + w_n)_n$.

For the opposite direction "$\Leftarrow$" assume that a limit point of $(z_n + w_n)_n$. Applying the $\Rightarrow$ part to $\tilde z_n = z_n + w_n$ and $\tilde w_n = -w_n$ implies that $z$ is a limit point of
$$
 \tilde z_n + \tilde w_n = (z_n + w_n) + (-w_n) = z_n \, .
$$

you can apply the same argument to $z_n = (z_n + w_n) - w_n$.

Comment: I guess that I dont have to prove your addendum to "$\Rightarrow$". It has already been proven during lecture.

Comment: So for "$\Leftarrow$": Let $z$ be the limit point of $(z_n+w_n)_{n\geq 1}$. As $w_n\overset{n\to \infty}\longrightarrow 0$ and $z_n = (z_n + w_n) - w_n$. We know that $z_n = \overbrace{(z_n + w_n)}^{=z}-0=z$.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: You don't have to *repeat* the argument. What I meant that you *apply* the $\implies$ part to $\tilde z_n = z_n + w_n$ and $\tilde w_n = -w_n$.

Comment: I guess that now we're talking at cross purposes...

Comment: Don't I have to prove that I can take the limits by themself: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n +\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: Your argument is built on that fact. If it has not been proven  before then you would have to prove it here.

Comment: Hmm, I am not that pleased with the proof anymore, do you know about an alternative proof?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: What exactly does not “please” you? I cannot guess what you are looking for.

Comment: Can I assume $z_n = (z_n + w_n) - w_n$ without proving it? Moreover I don't really understand "$\Leftarrow$"

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: Are you asking if  $a = (a+b) - b$ holds for real numbers? – I have extended the answer, hopefully it is clear now.